# Getstream- How to get a trending hashtags?

Tags: getstream-io

If the hashtag for 10 activities has python and 15 activities for techie,then need a trending hashtag how do i filter that?

trending hashtag 1:techie and hashtag 2:python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how do you want to display this? Something showing the most hashtags first, then next highest, etc? I would think an aggregated feed that follows all your hashtag feeds would work here, and you aggregate on the hashtag. Then you'll need to sort on your own before displaying, as we don't allow ranking on aggregated feeds.

If that's not what you're trying to do please elaborate. Thanks!